# Prevent data loss when pushing app update using MDM

Tags: ios, objective-c, mdm

My application stores data offline (using sqlite) and when it goes online, it syncs (user initiated event) the data with the central server.

The application is enterprise, and has been distributed using `MDM`. However, whenever I push an update to my app, the old app data gets wiped out completely, and the new app gets installed silently.

This is how I am forming my database

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *dbPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    databaseName = @"abc.sqlite";
    databasePath = [dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath])
    {
        const char *newPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    }
}
```

How can I stop this from happening? Is there a way to both install and update and keep the old app data intact (like when we update Facebook or Watsapp application).

Comment: This behavior is not "usual" when using MDM and enterprise apps. Must be something how you handle your data storage.

Comment: I am storing it in sqlite database. Do you have any idea what can go wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with some additional information/code i. e. are you using core data, how do you access the sqlite file etc. That would help.

Comment: Does the problem also happen if you manually update that app or push it through TestFlight?

Comment: Have not tried pushing it through test flight yet. There is nothing wrong with the way I am forming my database.. right?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @muenzpraeger that the behavior is unusual. In iOS the new version of the app is installed to a new location (with a new UUID absolute path) then the data is copied from the original folder to the new folder. Finally the original folder is deleted.

The problem might be that your SQLlite database is stored in one of the temp folders that won't be carried over during the installation. Can you confirm where you are storing the database. It should be under your Documents folder.

Comment: edited my answer to include how I am making my database.